# '[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**Hello Guys,**

Stumbled upon these types of warnings on VueJS while running karma tests:

`'[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined`"

Although the `enabled` prop is used like: `something.enabled` and `something` is coming from:

```
computed: {
   ...mapState(['app', 'something'])
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately we can't determine the problem from only the code you've provided. With that in mind, the error is clear: you're attempting to read the `enabled` property on a value that's `undefined`, i.e. you're doing `some_val.enabled` where `some_val == undefined`. If you want the source of the error narrowed down, you'll need to provide more relevant code snippets.

Comment: I just stated above that the `some_val` is `something` but I found the problem, it's the karma factory was empty for the `something` object, thanks anyways :)